# Clarify probability solution re. birthdays

Tags: probability, self-study

I have a problem regarding birthdays that involve the possible birthdays a group of 5 people can have within the 7 days of the week.

My solution to this was 5^7 total possibilities, but I'm not sure if that's correct? What intuition is needed for this?

EDIT: So, my issue is I'm not sure how to go about this. I know I should use multiplication principle. However, how does one figure out if it's 5^7, 7^5, 7! (5 times) etc. . . .

Comment: "intuition": the multiplication principle. And, your answer is **wrong**.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I already am using the multiplication principle. However, in the wrong way. Perhaps it makes more sense that instead of considering it as 7 days a week with 5 people each, (5x5x5x5x5x5x5) it makes more sense the other way around? I just don't know how to determine which one makes more sense really.

Comment: Consider a simpler problem. What if there were only **2** people? How many possible birthday-day of week combinations could they have? You can count these out manually w/o any math, if you need. Then you can try to scale the solution up.

Comment: ahh. I got 49 options which is 7^2. So . . . . the pattern is just the other way around from what I did then (7^5, not 5^7). If that's correct, thanks for the tip! I'll keep in mind to think of problems simpler

Comment: That's right, @user77364. Nice work.

Comment: Remember that (in some countries at least) births on Saturday and Sunday are less common than on other days because doctors like not working at weekends.

Answer (score 1):

So the first person can have his/her birthday on any of the seven days of the week: seven possible outcomes. For the second person, there'd be also seven possibilities, that could occur for each one of the 7 scenarios regarding the birthday of the first person, for a total of $7^2$ possible outcomes. And so on, until you reach your five-person group, which would give you a combined sample space of $7^5$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Please read our policies for `[self-study]` questions on the tag's [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Be cautious of providing full answers.

Comment: OK. I'll erase.